# Moving from quarkus-resteasy to quarkus-resteasy-reactive what about application using ThreadLocal?

Tags: java, quarkus, vert.x, thread-local

As stated in the documentation passing from quarkus-resteasy to reactive is as simple as changing only maven dependency and it should works.

In our quarkus project, we create a session in `@PreMatching` filter and save it in thread local. In other filters we update session with other information. Session information are then used in all services and resources.

After somme performance tests, even we have more RAM and CPU we see only 200 threads used in  prometheus. We have the possibility to change max-thread in properties file or moving to reactive programming.

At start point, we changed to quarkus reactive and we experienced the following problems:

When adding reactive to quarkus-resteasy we experienced the following:
The first thread that intercept request is an event loop thread. Then it delegate execution to worker thread if method annotated with @Blocking, else it continue execution with event loop thread.

**Problem 1)** Blocking method:
All information added to session in `@PreMatching` filter are lost. But information added in the session from other filters  with priority for example  `@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION - 10)` are present in the worker thread.

**Problem 2)** NoBlocking method:
With a few requests all thing works fine, but with 100 parallel requests, we experience a random losing session information. After googling, event loop thread use a different context (Vertx thread context) and I haven't find any documentation that explain how to move from ThreadLocal to Vertx Thread context while moving from quarkus to quarkus reactive.

**Problem 3)** Transform method to return Uni, ThreadLocal information are propagated but I haven't yet test it under load. [UPDATE] same as **Problem 2)**

**Problem 4)** Cant find how to run integration tests in Vertx Thread

Any help on how to move projects using ThreadLocal to anything else when moving to quarkus reactive will be appreciated

Comment: Have you read https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive#request-or-response-filters? Another option would be to rearchitect your Services to not use ThreadLocal, but instead be passed the necessary information from the Resources (which can obtain it from the request context)

Comment: Yes, I already declare filters in jax-rs way. It will be hard to change all methods signature to pass every thing in params. What about LogManager MDC based on  ThreadLocal. RequestId must be present in all logs

Comment: Have you read https://quarkus.io/guides/context-propagation

Comment: Indeed, context propagation is one way to hear.

Comment: I'm already using context propagation before passing to quarkus reactive. This does not resolve problem with quarkus reactive.

Comment: Using vertx context to save session info for eventloop thread only and continue using thread local for non eventloop thread seems to be working but I'm not sure if somewhere quarkus switch between eventloop/worker threads

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use Vertx `ContextLocals`, take a look at this https://pt.quarkus.io/guides/duplicated-context